# Setting element visiblity with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, is there some property on an element that I can set to true/false to control the visibility of that element?

Basically, I need something like this:

```
$(this).visible(someCondition);
```

`toggle()` won't work because I need to be able to tell it whether or not it will be shown.

`show()` and `hide()` work, but I have to do this:

```
if (someCondition) {
    $(this).show();
}
else {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Which, as you can see, is not nearly as elegant as the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`toggle(someCondition)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will work.
It takes an optional boolean parameter.

Comment: Perfect, never knew that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As SLak suggested, toggle() works.  If you are using classes that have visibility states set (i.e., display: none or visibility:hidden), you can also use toggleClass().

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.visibleCond = function( cond ) {
    if ( cond ) {
        return this.show();
    } else {
        return this.hide();
    };
};
```

Then:

```
$(this).visibleCond(someCondition);
```

And fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3daq/

Comment: Sure, this works, but it's totally unnecessary given SLak's answer.